# Sharepoint 2013 site keeps asking for credentials with and error message

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, login, credentials

I am working on `On premise Sharepoint 2013`. I face an issue where the login popup for credentials repeatedly comes with an error message `Your connection is not private` and asks for credentials.

This process is repeated again and again. I have other team members working on the same web application but they do not face this issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set ‘Automatic logon with current user name and password in Local intranet zone and Trusted sites of IE:

Navigate to IE->Internet options->Security tab->Local intranet and Trusted sites->Custom level->choose automatic logon with current user name and password:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me! Can help me with some other solution?